# rewrite rule for ip not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following apache redirect rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com  [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^82\.238\.254\.181 
RewriteRule (.*) http\://www\.example\.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What I want that the IP adress as well should be redirected to the www domain. Now when I type the IP in the browser than it's becoming the www as prefix.

Comment: Looking at your question, it appears English is not your native language; it's not clear what you are experiencing / hoping to achive.. `Now when I type the IP in the browser than it's becoming the www as prefix` - could you provide examples of what you type, what the URL is re-written to, and what you expect it should be re-written as.

Comment: sorry, so the problem practically looks as it follows. If there is a request on ip than I got something like www.82.238.254.181, instead should the ip redirected to www.example.com.

Answer (score 0):

`HTTP_HOST` contains the value of the HTTP `Host` header as sent by the client.

You won't find an IP address there. If a user connects to `http://82.238.254.181` there won't be
a `Host` header .

You should use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =""
```